# How to create ajax update time?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm creating partial view.
I need to get number of seconds that have passed since 2012.04.01

```
public PartialViewResult SitePowered()
{
    var dateTime = new DateTime(2012, 4, 1);
    var totalSeconds = (DateTime.Now - dateTime).TotalSeconds;
    ViewBag.TotalSeconds = totalSeconds;
    return PartialView("SitePowered");
}
```

view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.getJSON("/Home/SitePowered", null, setTime);
    });
</script>
@ViewBag.TotalSeconds секунд
```

but it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do something like this:

**Action:**

```
public ActionResult SitePowered()
{
    var dateTime = new DateTime(2012, 4, 1);
    var totalSeconds = (DateTime.Now - dateTime).TotalSeconds;
    return Json(new { seconds = totalSeconds });
}
```

**Client-side:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.getJSON("/Home/SitePowered", function(result) {
              // Do something here with result.seconds
              alert(result.seconds);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope it helps.